# PyLint W0231 super-init-not-called with __init__ of grandparent

Tags: python, inheritance, pylint, method-resolution-order

I make a `Child` class that use methods from `Parent` class witch not present in `GrandParent`. But in the `Child.__init__()` class I don't want to get some effects from `Parent.__init__()` and instead I call call `GrandParent.__init__()`

```
class GrandParent():
    ...

class Parent(GrandParent):    
    def __init__(self):
        GrandParent.__init__(self)
        ...


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        GrandParent.__init__(self)
        ...
```

With this code i got next warnings from pylint

```
 W0233: __init__ method from a non direct base class 'GrandParent' is called (non-parent-init-called)
 W0231: __init__ method from base class 'Parent' is not called (super-init-not-called)
```

What is the correct way to fix this warnings ?

(or disable this warnings for Child is proper solution ?)

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):  # pylint: disable=W0233
        GrandParent.__init__()   # pylint: disable=W0231
        ...
```

Comment: If you do not want the effects from the init of the parent, then usually the child should not be a sub-class of the parent. Perhaps it should directly be a sub-class of the GrandParent then. Aim for simplicity and straightforward inheritance rather than complex restricted inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try multiple ways such as:

```
GrandParent.__init__(self)
super().super().__init__(self)
super(GrandParent, self).__init__()
```

but the error will still be there either as:

- `super-init-not-called`
- or `bad-super-call` (`super(GrandParent, self)...`)
- or even as useless super call to the immediate parent.

I suppose it's meant as a warning for not initializing the immediate class in the class `__mro__` by mistake if you work with inheritance and you can to turn off it with a pylint disable:

```
# pylint: disable=super-init-not-called
```

but you are messing with the `__mro__` chain by such calls.

What you can do is allow cascading through the `Child.__mro__` items upward i.e. `Child` -> `Parent` -> `GrandParent` (-> `object`) while skipping by class reference in an `__init__`:

```
class Parent(GrandParent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        if self.__class__ == Child:
            return
```

which does not trigger the PyLint warnings and allows the correct behavior explicitly and without skipping any required items in `__mro__`.

IMO it's much cleaner preserving the `__mro__` which seems what PyLint's intent is as well by `super-init-not-called` warning. On the other hand, it's kind of tricky and hides the code in a completely different class and that will make the debugging in the future annoying if some properties from `Parent` will be missing and no comment/disable warning are present in `Child` class.

If you want to pull the methods out of the `GrandParent` class only, simply go with the "mixins" classes which is what [Django REST Framework is using](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py) and don't write any `__init__` for those (or if, then don't forget `super().__init__()` to continue in `__mro__` chain!).

```
class GrandParent:
    def __init__(self):
        print("> GrandParent __init__()")

class Mixin:
    def mymethod(self):
        print("Hey")

class Parent(Mixin, GrandParent):
    def __init__(self):
        print("> Parent __init__()")
        super().__init__()

class Child(Mixin, GrandParent):
    def __init__(self):
        print("> Child __init__()")
        super().__init__()

Child().mymethod()
# > Child __init__()
# > GrandParent __init__()
# Hey

Parent().mymethod()
# > Parent __init__()
# > GrandParent __init__()
# Hey
```

which will basically be the same situation you have with `Child` -> `Parent` -> `GrandParent` but `Mixin` itself doesn't have (any useful) `__init__` which will cause your code only from `GrandParent` to execute due to `Mixin.__init__()` being empty hence doing visually the same thing as with `if self.__class__ == Child: return` but without any hacks + with increased readability.